# Check If one Field Exists, Then select another field in the same Model of Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have some couple of shops in my Model and I want to check if there is banana in any of the shops. I used default DRF ID field as the primary key for each shop.

Here is my **Model.py**

```
class Shops(models.Model):
    STATE = Choices(
        ('Egg', 'EGG'),
        ('Banana', 'BANANA'),
        ('Orange', 'ORANGE'),        
    )
    shop = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    items = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=STATE, default='Egg')
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ChoicesField(choices=Shops.STATE)
    class Meta:
        model = Shops
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class CheckShopsView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        res = Shops.objects.get(id=id)
        if id:
            serializers = ShopSerializer(res)
            if Shops.objects.filter(items="Banana"):
                return Response({
                    'status': 'Success',
                    "Shop": serializers.data
                }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({
                    'status': 'Not Applicable',
                    "Shop": serializers.data
                }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally resolved it:
in my views.py I removed the first if condition and added id=id in the filter method. Which means if shop id is available in the id field and items field = banana, return success. My new Views.py looks like this:

```
class CheckShopsView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
    res = Shops.objects.get(id=id)
    serializers = ShopSerializer(res)
    if Shops.objects.filter(id=id,items="Banana"):
       return Response({
           'status': 'Success',
           "Shop": serializers.data
       }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
       else:
          return Response({
             'status': 'Not Applicable',
             "Shop": serializers.data
          }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)nter code here
```